# Control transparency of smoother and confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, transparency, confidence-interval

I'm refering to this SO question from 2 years ago, with ggplot : [Adjust Transparency (alpha) of stat_smooth lines, not just transparency of Confidence Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19474552/3871924)

The first method suggested allows to set the alpha transparency of the confidence interval alone:

```
ggplot(head(airquality, 60), aes(x=Day, y=Temp, color=factor(Month))) +
  geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE, alpha=1.0)
```

[image]

The second method allows to set the alpha transparency for the line itself, but you *loose* the confidence interval in the meantime, even with `se=TRUE`:

```
ggplot(head(airquality, 60), aes(x=Day, y=Temp, color=factor(Month))) +
  geom_point() + geom_line(stat='smooth', method = "lm", se=TRUE, alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

**My question**: How to control the transparency of both the smoothing line and the confidence interval?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This calculates the model twice. But normally that shouldn't be a performance issue.

```
ggplot(head(airquality, 60), aes(x=Day, y=Temp, color=factor(Month))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_ribbon(stat='smooth', method = "lm", se=TRUE, alpha=0.1, 
              aes(color = NULL, group = factor(Month))) +
  geom_line(stat='smooth', method = "lm", alpha=0.3)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: thanks, that works fine! I presume there is no direct method to do this. NB: i think the `se=TRUE` in the geom_ribbon can be removed?

Comment: @agenis are you aware of a direct method to this as of 2017? Seems counterintuitive to go through the workaround

Comment: @Dan can you post a new answer?

Comment: It seems `geom_ribbon` does not work if `method="loess"`

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way I know how to do this. I'm sure you could also use it with a `scale_color_manual` as well if you have more specific color scales in mind.

```
ggplot(head(airquality, 60), aes(x=Day, y=Temp, 
                                 color=factor(Month))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(alpha=0.2) + #toggle this alpha for error bar opacity
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE, alpha = 0.9) + #toggle this alpha for line opacity 
  theme_minimal()
```

Open to questions, comments, or improvements.