# How to add to the face labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I was wonder how to show the result of `paste("n =", ns)` next to the facet labels in my plot below?

```
library(tidyverse)

dd <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/3.csv')

ns <- dd %>% group_by(schoolid) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n)

ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = year, y = math, group = factor(childid)))+
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, size = .1, formula = y~offset(.5*x)) + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(schoolid)) 

# Tried the following without success:
# + 
  # geom_label(aes(x=4, y=5), label= paste("n =", ns), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: @AllanCameron, your answer is wrong. Please note I want `paste("n =", ns)` where I have defined `ns` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a named vector and pass into `labeller`

```
ns1 <- setNames(paste0(unique(dd$schoolid), ' (', ns, ')'), 
                  unique(dd$schoolid) )
ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = year, y = math, 
            group = factor(childid)))+
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, size = .1, 
            formula = y~offset(.5*x)) + 
    facet_wrap(~schoolid, labeller = labeller(schoolid = ns1)) + 
            guides(fill = FALSE)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to set `alpha=.1` in `geom_smooth()` but it seems it has no effect? `... geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, size = .1, formula = y~offset(.5*x),  alpha =.01) ...`

Comment: @rnorouzian may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474552/adjust-transparency-alpha-of-stat-smooth-lines-not-just-transparency-of-confi) helps